# How to generate data in one method and pass that data into another method but in the same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, watir-webdriver

How do I generate data in one method and pass that data into another method but in the same class?

I have a Ruby class with two methods. Is there any way to call `create_data_hash` and return the results as two variables into `rest_call`?

I also need to be able to call the methods `create_data_hash.email` and return "foo@foo.com", and `create_data_hash.password` and return "strongpassword".

I need to be able to use those values in other parts of the program, but yet still need this class to handle the generation of the data.

```
require 'json'

module New
  class Generator

    def create_data_hash
    email = 'foo@foo.com'
    password = 'strongpassword'
    end

    def rest_call(user_email, user_password)
      data_hash = { email: user_email,
               password: user_password ,
               info: "user",
               name: "JohnDoe",
              }
      @random = endpoint_tester_class.new
      @random.endpoint_test(data_hash.to_json)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Make data_hash an instance variable (`@data_hash`), and expose as `attr_accessor`

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the next technique.

```
def accept_multi(*args)
  puts "args are: #{args}"
  puts "args class is #{args.class}"
end

def accept_two(one, two)
  puts "first arg is #{one}", "second arg is #{two}"
end

def return_two
  return "a", "b"
end

# now run the code
accept_multi return_two
# prints:
# args are: [["a", "b"]]
# args class is Array

# do not forget '*' symbol
accept_two *return_two
# prints:
# first arg is a
# second arg is b

return_two.class
# prints
# Array
```

NOTE: if you will use it, do not forget to check arity of your methods. For example, if you call `accept_two *[1, 2, 3]`, `ArgumentError` exception will be raised.

Also, you are able to use instance variables.

```
class TestClass
  def set_vars
    @one = 1
    @two = 2
  end

  def print_vars
    puts @one, @two
  end

  def process
    set_vars
    print_vars
  end
end

tc = TestClass.new
tc.process
```